# ajax CORS error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

i have an API which support CORS, but some of them is not support CORS yet. i do the request using ajax/jquery. how do i handle the error if the request is failed due to CORS restriction? eg, pop an alert to notify user that it's failed.

i tried this.

```
function poster(path, body, callback){
    var url = 'http://mysite/';
    url += path;
    try{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'},
            success: function(result){
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    }catch(e){
        callback({'error':'Cross Origin Issue'});
    }
}
```

this doesn't work, my browser (chrome) still throw error to the console. so, how do i handle this, so it will call the callback function instead of throwing error to the console?

Comment: There is a built in `error` function in jQ's AJAX ya know :)

Comment: @tymeJV I've had times when $.ajax gets the wrong return type of data, sometimes its fails silently and does not call the error callback. But yes, in this case, setting the error callback is definitely the first port of call.

Comment: @tymeJV can you share specifics of the `error()` parameters to identify the CORS error?